# Knockout computed is triggered too many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a `viewModel` and a template which renders data based on an `if` condition:

```
<!-- ko template: { data: selectedFolder, if: isTemplateVisible, name: 'selectedFoldersProperties-template' } --><!-- /ko -->
```

I think that the template is being rendered 4 times consecutively, and one of the reasons is that `isTemplateVisible` is a `ko.computed`.

If i change `if: isTemplateVisible` to `if: selectedFolder`, then the template gets rendered 2 times consecutively.

I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SR27g/3/) demo.

You will see that "hit" is output-ed for 4 times after the button has been pressed.

Is there a reason why the function gets called so many times?

```
<button id="button" type="button">
    Set folder
</button>

<div>
    <!-- ko template: { data: selectedFolder, if: isTemplateVisible, name: 'selectedFoldersProperties-template' } --><!-- /ko -->
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="selectedFoldersProperties-template">
    <span data-bind="text: FolderName"></span>

    <ul data-bind="foreach: $root.getFiles($data)">
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text: FileName"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>

var viewModel = {
    selectedFolder: ko.observable(null),
    getFiles: function(folderData) {
        console.log("hit");
        return [
            { FileName: "File 1" },
            { FileName: "File 2" }
        ];   
    }
};
viewModel.isTemplateVisible = ko.computed(function(){
    return this.selectedFolder();
}, viewModel);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    viewModel.selectedFolder({
        FolderName: "Folder 1"
    });
};
```

Comment: Your `computed` is only being evaluated once per click, for what that's worth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `isTemplateVisible` has a dependency on `selectedFolder` so that makes you template to re-render.

change  `isTemplateVisible` to not be a computed first:

```
viewModel.isTemplateVisible = function(){
    return this.selectedFolder();
};
```

and then change your if binding on the template to execute the value out:

```
if: isTemplateVisible()
```

then your tmeplate won't run twice due to the dependency.

[Here is the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vgUA/)

---

**Alternatively**

You can simply the whole thing by removing the iftemplateisvisible stuff:

```
<button id="button" type="button">
    Set folder
</button>

<div>
    <!-- ko  if: selectedFolder -->
    <!-- ko template: { data: selectedFolder, name: 'selectedFoldersProperties-template' } --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="selectedFoldersProperties-template">
    <span data-bind="text: FolderName"></span>

    <ul data-bind="foreach: $root.getFiles($data)">
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text: FileName"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

and viewmodel:

```
var viewModel = {
    selectedFolder: ko.observable(null),
    getFiles: function(folderData) {
        console.log("hit");
        return [
            { FileName: "File 1" },
            { FileName: "File 2" }
        ];   
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    viewModel.selectedFolder({
        FolderName: "Folder 1"
    });
};
```

[Here is fiddle for the second solution](http://jsfiddle.net/7vgUA/5/)

---

**Further clarification to why you have this issue**

[If you want to delve deeper in what's going wrong I have created another fiddle which is time stamping your template:](http://jsfiddle.net/FpbRY/1/)

So what is happening is that on the same comment binding you have an observable and a computed which are interdependent, therefore they are causing your template to render twice inseatd of only one time.

So you either as I suggested need to separate them on different bindings so one has resolved by the time you are evaluating the other or you eliminate one of them.

If you change your binding to not have inter-dependency and be for example:

```
if: selectedFolder(), data: selectedFolder
```

Then the loop won't occur as you don't have two things dependent on each other and responsible for rendering the template.

Based on this also Throttle is not going to help you as all it does it to delay the value change of an observable which would delay your first render, followed by the interdependency loop caused by cross referencing.

---

getFiles function runs twice due to being a self executing function on your binding. It tuns once when it's being placed on the page and again when it is its turn to run inside foreach.

[This can be demonstrated here](http://jsfiddle.net/FpbRY/48/) where you can see that the callers of your getFiles function are both `function (){return $root.getFiles() }` from your template.

If you change that function to be `foreach: $root.getFiles` without the parenthesis and make getFiles an observableArray so it gets resolved by knockout then you won't have the twice execution issue.

Comment: Great solution, thank you. However, why does it render for 2 times? Can I use the `throttle` extender or something like this to avoid this?

Comment: Added another fiddle for you with time stamps to see what's going wrong

Comment: @XGreen Why is it logging hit twice even after removing interdependency?

Comment: @XGreen Ok, this makes sense. I've realized that if i put the if statement on the template wrapper, then it gets evaluated only twice [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FpbRY/5/). However, the two times render is still a mistery

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are having foreach binding.

This code `<ul data-bind="foreach: $root.getFiles($data)">` will cause to compute it 4 times.

Hope its clear

Comment: You say that because `getFiles` returns a list with two items? if i make it return only 1 item or 6, the function still gets called 4 times